# SQLite GUI editor

Tags: windows, desktop-client, gui, sqlite

I'm working with SQLite. The database is used by a software. For some purposes I have to see the database and edit it. Can anyone recommend me software for doing this?

Requirements:

- Show database/tables
- Edit database/tables
- Show overview about database (all tables and linked tables)
- Execute SQL statements
- Autocomplete function for SQL statements
- Link tables
- Easy to handle

At the moment I use [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/), but it is not able to show a graphical overview about the tables of a database.

The software should run on a PC under Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could take a look at [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/features.html). This application has a large number of features and is available in both a free and a paid version (which has more features like data importing from various file formats, exporting to various file formats, more drag and drop database manipulation, automatic query generation and some repair tools).

You can take a look at the full and comprehensive feature list on the [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/features.html) website but relating specifically to your list of requirements:

- Has a graphical interface which shows databases and tables
- Allows editing of databases and tables
- Shows an overview of the database showing all tables
- Allows the execution of SQL queries

Here are a couple of screenshots of SQLite Expert from their website:

[image]

[image]

Additionally, SQLite Expert can be customised further with skins and plugins to add further functionality.

Comment: Nice one, Flyk! Might it be worth mentioning *here* that there's a cost-free "personal edition", as well as a "professional edition" for ~$60, and what the major differences are between the two? (+1 meanwhile from me ;)

Comment: I had kinda hinted at that but I've fleshed it out a bit.

Comment: Mee too, checking for it; didn't see a price tag, and thus completely missed you mentioned "free" and "paid" ;) Thanks for the update!

Comment: As of Oct, 2016, the Visual Query Builder has been removed from the Free edition, is only available in  the Pro edition. For Linux users: The software runs under wine (works for me without much tinkering).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **[Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/)** to work with my SQLite databases. One reason for my selection was I can invoke it from the command-line while passing the database file to work with.

#### Requested features:

- *Show database/tables:* Sure.
- *Edit database/tables:* Yes.
- *Show overview about database:* in a tree-structure, so you can dive in where you like.
- *Execute SQL statements:* Features an SQL editor with syntax highlighting etc.
- *Autocomplete function for SQL statements:* Supported
- *Link tables:* Not sure what you mean by that, sorry
- *GUI:* See screenshots
- *Easy to handle:* a little subjective, but I'd say "yes".

[image: Editor on Linux] [image: Design a table on Windows]
<sup>Selected screenshots: SQL editor (on Linux), graphical Table-designer (on windows); click images for larger variants</sup>

#### Personal notes:

As mentioned initially, there are some other criteria to count on the plus-side:

- possibility to start the GUI from command-line, passing the database file to work with as argument
- support for many platforms, including Linux, Mac OS, OS/2, Windows
- graphical query-builder for those unfamiliar with SQL (or simply in need of some assistance)
- free (as in "free beer", i.e. cost-free)

Comment: The link is broken; do you know where the official site is now?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Link works for me, but seems to redirect to http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/ currently.

Comment: Yes, something is sporadic.  Can access that site about 20% of the time.  Here is the GitHub repository https://github.com/pvanek/sqliteman and the sourceforge repository: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/

Comment: I just discovered that a portable version is available for Windows: http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqliteman-portable

Comment: Also the one in sourceforge seems portable!

Answer (score 3):

"DB Browser for SQLite" (DB4S)

- https://sqlitebrowser.org/
- https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser

seems to do most of what you require, though I am uncertain about the "link" functionality.

Comment: Much better than the 2 above imo and for my purpose, which is to be able to edit cells of the database manually easily...

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [**sqlite-gui**](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui) for Windows. This tool has most standard features such code highlighting and export/import and some unique/rare:

- Search in whole database ([Heidi](https://www.heidisql.com/) has it too)
- Charts (hi, DB4S!)
- Database diagram (bad styled; similar [Valentina Studio](https://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview))
- Pack of extensions is included
- [Quick references](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/wiki#quick-references) to view related data
- [Terminal mode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/master/resources/terminal.webp)
- [Extract-Transform-Load](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-wf) tool
- Database comparison (schema and data)
- Disable/Enable indexes/triggers

[image]

P.S. SQLiteStudio has taken great steps since 2014 and now it's a pretty cool.