# SQLite viewer for Mac OS X

Tags: gratis, osx, sqlite

I need to inspect an SQLite file on Mac.

What viewer should I use?

Requirements:

- Free, ideally open source
- Browse schema, data.
- Run queries

*Bonus if updated in near real time when the file is modified by an external program, no need to click "Refresh".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/):

- Free and open source (and still maintained)
- Browse schema, data.
- Run queries

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Firefox addon [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/):

- Free and open source (and still maintained)
- Browse schema, data.
- Run queries

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be found at Thunderbird addons site. It works fine with Firefox 52.

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to take a look at **[Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/)** (see [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1061/185) for details and screenshots). According to [its download page at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/files/sqliteman/1.2.2/), a MacOS version is "in progress", and *you can use 1.3.x series, it's working* (quote from there).

How does it meet your requirements:

- **Free, ideally open source:** It's free alright, and its [code is available at Github](https://github.com/pvanek/sqliteman)
- **Browse schema, data:** Definitely – that's what I mainly use it for :)
- **Run queries:** Yes. It has a query editor with syntax highlighting even.

Not sure about your "bonus feature", as I didn't check that.

Giving you an example screenshot before you head to the [other mentioned answer of mine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1061/185):

[image: Sqliteman on Linux]
<sup>Sqliteman running on Linux (source: [Homepage](http://sqliteman.com/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You may like my app [SQLPro for SQLite](https://www.sqlitepro.com) ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id586001240?mt=12)).

It fits all of your requirements other than being free/open source. There is a [read-only version](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sqlpro-for-sqlite-read-only/id635299994?mt=12) available on the Mac App Store, which allows you to view all of your data, but does not allow modifying schemas or data.

The ‘bonus’ feature (automatic refresh) is handled as well. By default the database will detect external changes and reload automatically. This can be disabled via the application preferences (although reloads can still be performed via keyboard shortcuts).

Some of the neat features it includes are:

- Syntax highlighting & Autocomplete (sometimes called intellisense).
- Customizable themes allowing the query editor to be completely customized.
- The ability to run multiple queries at one time (and a customizable run query shortcut).
- Primary key detection in the query results. When primary keys are detected you can update results & delete rows directly from the grid.
- Errors in queries will be underlined.

[image: SQLPro for SQLite screenshot 1]

There is a full schema designer. SQLPro for SQLite allows you to add/update/delete:

- Tables
- Indexes
- Foreign Keys and
- Triggers

[image: Column designer]
[image: Foreign key designer]
In addition:

- Tables can be imported & exported from/as CSV, XML or JSON.
- A query history browser so that you may see queries run in the past.
- Favourite queries can be stored and reused.
- The results grid can be searched (either via the Cmd - F keyboard shortcut or by right clicking the results grid and choosing find).

There is a seven day trial available via the website. If you purchase via our [webstore](https://sqlitepro.com/store.php), use the promo code STACK25 to save 25%.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Comment: Gratis is a hard requirement here, unfortunately.

Comment: The linked read-only version seems to no longer exist. Unfortunate, as that’s exactly what I need.